# Filter string for select drop down list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selection list as described below:

```
<select id="edit-type" class="form-select ajax-processed valid" name="type">
   <option selected="selected" value="text">Text</option>
   <option value="select">Drop Down List</option>
   <option value="file">Single File Submission</option>
   <option value="license">License</option>
</select>
```

I would like to user jQuery to find this select element but I want to use the name attribute to find it (not the id or class attributes as they may change). I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
$(':select[name="type"]').live('change', function() {....
```

I am new to JavaScript so I guess I am missing something fundamental here. I thought this would work. Can I not use `:select[name="type"]` as a selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `:` before the selector

```
$('select[name="type"]').live('change', function() {....
```

or

```
$(':input[name="type"]').live('change', function() {.... // if you have any other input with the same it will select that too. SO better to go with first option.
```

Also make sure this is under `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

See:

Just to update about your question on `:input`

[:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

*from doc*

> The :input selector basically selects all form controls.
>   Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").

Comment: Or change `:select` to  `:input`.

Comment: also, might as well use `.on('change', function {..} `  as `.live() is now deprecated`

Comment: @ginman Not sure if OP is using the version of jquery less than 1.7 so no `on` for him.

Comment: One question to help my understanding - why remove the : before the selector when you would need the colon if searching for an input (ie :input)? Is that an idiosyncrasy of jQuery?

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't notice that was from his original post.

Comment: @user5013 :input is used to basically select all the form controls with the given name `The :input selector basically selects all form controls.`

Comment: Updated the answer with more clarification of `:input` selector

Answer (score 0):

I think Below code may help:

You can find element by name by using:

```
   $('select[name="type"]').live('change', function()
```

And to get selected option, you can use :

```
$('select[name="type"] option:selected').text();
$('select[name="type"] option:selected').val(
```